# "Yes, I will be"

Tags: grammaticality, auxiliary-verbs, ellipses

This question was spurred by some comments that sprung underneath an ELL question of mine. The comments have since been deleted.

> **User 1**: There's nothing wrong with "Yes, I will be". (I agree that "*I'll be" is incorrect though.)
>
> **User 2**: Are you sure? I don't think, "Yes, I will be" is correct. I Ngrammed ["yes i will be"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=yes%20i%20will%20be&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=) and got a result of zero. Also Ngrammed "yes, i will be" and "yes" got positive results, but "i will be" got [zero results, too](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=yes%2C%20i%20will%20be&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cyes%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ci%20will%20be%3B%2Cc0).
>
> **User 1**: @_______: Yes, I'm sure. Your ngram is wrong - remember the word "I" is always capitalised; if you fix that you do get results. (Most of them are "Yes, I will be xxx", rather than just "Yes, I will be.", but if you keep searching you will find odd examples of the latter.)
>
> **User 2:** Cont'd from previous comment. I checked the Ngram results for ["Yes I will be"](https://www.google.it/search?q=%22yes%20i%20will%20be%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=cr&ei=QLxbWIHdOaXNgAaE_pPgAQ) and could not find any examples. Ngram results for ["Yes, I will be."](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Yes%2C%20I%20will%20be.&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CYes%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20will%20be%20.%3B%2Cc0) and ["Yes I will be."](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Yes%20I%20will%20be.&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=) were also zero.
>
> **User 2**: @______ And I realize that "I" is always capitalized. But I hadn't turned on case sensitivity, so now I'm confused why "Yes i will be" and "Yes I will be" returns different results.

In light of the various Ngram and Google Books results reported by User 1, it appears that he may be right. Is he?

---

### Why am I asking?

In every grammar and English course book I have ever used with learners or for myself, I have never *ever* read the short answer: *Yes, I will be*. These books simply don't "teach" this type of response, the classic short answers to questions beginning with the auxiliary, *will*, are always given as either  ***Yes, I will*** or *No, I won't*. The two questions which I posted were the following:

- Will you be coming to the staff party on Thursday?
- **Will you be having cake?**

In the second question, I offered the following list of short answers:

> 1. Yes, thank you.
> 2. Yes, I will.
> 3. Yes, I will be
> 4. Yes, I will do.

- Why is answer no.3 grammatical?
- What evidence is there to support it?
- Is answer number 4 (above) ungrammatical?

An American user suggested that "Yes, I will do" was wrong. (Please refer to the linked question below, for further details)

Thank you

---

<sub>The ELL related questions which sparked the above discussion</sub>

1. [Why is “I'll be”, wrong as a short answer?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/112907/why-is-ill-be-wrong-as-a-short-answer?noredirect=1&lq=1)
2. [Will you be having cake?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/112942/will-you-be-having-cake)

Comment: Is this a question on how to use Google grams search or on acceptability of a sentence?

Comment: @Mitch `comment 1`: User 1 was asking for *evidence*. If you hurry you can still see the trail of comments. `comment 2`: Is the title so ambiguous? `comment 3` Why can't we talk about grammar or acceptability on EL&U?

Comment: @Mari-LouA: I think User *2* was looking for evidence. User 1 is quite confident that it is grammatical ;-)

Comment: @psmears  Oh, yes the other way round. User 2 was looking for evidence, and seemed quite convinced there was none. Apologies.

Comment: @Mitch your last comment attracted 2 upvotes, which doesn't mean everyone agrees with you, because as we all know, comments cannot be DVed, so even if the DVs on *this* question don't bother me, (I can see  that it *appears* to be trivial) I'm curious to learn why `This is a great subject for chat but not for Q&A`? Without any sarcasm, sincerely, could you explain why you and two others think this Q is "off topic"? Is that it?

Comment: Without following all the prior discourse, which may or may not be relevant to the question, I can say that whether a short response to a question with material deleted is grammatical is entirely a matter of what the question is. And in writing, one can't tell what the material was because writing doesn't preserve intonation and stress, which indicate what's been deleted in context.

Comment: Therefore, outside of context, any discussion of whether _Yes, I will be_ is grammatical is (a) impossible without a question, because it might work for some and not for others, and (b) impossible in writing, because it would have to be pronounced correctly to be grammatical in context. So Ngrams, which only count **written** material, are irrelevant. In general, questions about (un)grammaticality are really about how difficult it appears to be to create an imaginary context in which it would be appropriate to say it. If it's easy, it's grammatical; the harder it gets, the less grammatical.

Comment: @JohnLawler For context, the debate was sparked by the  two ELL questions I linked, both of which contained questions in the present progressive *"Will you be coming to the staff party on Thursday?"* and *"Will you be having cake?"* Some users found the short answers: "Yes, I will be" and "Yes, I will do" slightly odd. As for you comment about Ngrams I suspected as much, but as i consider  **"I will be"** very polite, I'm surprised there isn't stronger evidence of its usage.

Comment: @Mari-LouA that's a discussion, which we should also take to chat. I've given comments there.

Comment: Thanks, @Mari-LouA. I'm not trying to join the discussion; I'm trying to figure out whether there is a question here that I can answer, and if so what it is. _Yes, I will be_ is OK because _Yes, I will_ is fine; and that has a stressed _will_. Adding _be_ doesn't shift the stress; adding _do_ doesn't, either (but it still sounds odd to me, because responses like _Yes, I'll do_ are not American). *_Yes, I'll_ is bad because you can't stress _I'll_; *_(Yes), I'll be_ is bad since adding _be_ doesn't shift stress and you still can't stress _I'll_. I don't see a specific question, though.

Comment: @JohnLawler well that's a pity. I thought the question title was straightforward, and user 2's comment in the discussion`Are you sure? I don't think, "Yes, I will be" is correct. `  clarified why I posted the question . I don't know how to fix my question, unless I ask a different, but related question. Maybe I should do that.

Comment: @Mitch I meant please add the link underneath the question, in case anyone wants to join in the discussion. I try to avoid chat if possible, I find it confusing to use.

Comment: I'm afraid I disregarded the title, since no one can ever **prove** anything about grammaticality, especially about transformed material like short answers. Proof is impossible in science; only mathematics and logic can prove something.

Comment: I should perhaps note that I rarely look down to see who's posting, and frequently disregard titles since they are so full of ungrammaticalities and false presuppositions. Nothing personal, honest.

Comment: As for User 2, opinions on grammaticality coming from anonymous speakers of anonymous languages in anonymous countries are another thing I frequently disregard. We see very strange (but equally strongly held) opinions on English grammaticality issued by English language students all the time here.

Answer (score 4):

Hmmf, well the question used to ask if someone could prove if this phrase was grammatical but this response inspired a edit removing that request for a proof. So what follows now seems a bit silly.  I invite the first editor so inclined to delete this down to where it says "regarding edit".

Yes, I will be proving that someone can prove "Yes, I will be." is grammatical. I will do this by making up a grammar where the string "Yes, I will be." is the only grammatically correct string in the whole grammar.  This makes proving it to be grammatical a tautology.  It must be correct since it is how the grammar was defined.  It's correct by definition.

Now, if you find that unsatisfying I invite you to cite a grammar definition that is formal enough to withstand the very idea of proofs.  Proofs are rigorous but only as good as the context from which they emerge.

Otherwise we're just having a subjective argument.  One that I'll win, only because my hat looks cooler. :)

As a side note, the only objection I know to this common usage is that it ends with a preposition.  And we all know [how Churchill felt about that](https://public.wsu.edu/%7Ebrians/errors/churchill.html).

Regarding edit:

> 3. Yes, I will be
>
> Why is answer no.3 grammatical?

It's not. Ya left off da period ya silly. No wait, that's punctuation. Yeah it's fine, if it means what it says. In fact I can imagine this exact phrasing being the point of the answer:

CandiedOrange took a piece of cake over to Mary while she was sitting with friends who were watching her unwrap gifts. CandiedOrange asked, "Will you be having cake?" Mary narrowed her eyes at this untimely interruption and responded, "Yes, I **will** be".

> What evidence is there to support it?

Speaking of my hat, when Luke says "I'm not afraid" Yoda says, what to me sounded like the only non-mangled English he ever spoke, "You will be".

So don't go disrespecting my childhood hero. : )

> 4. Yes, I will do.
>
> Is answer number 4 (above) ungrammatical?

This is what I mean by 'if it says what it means': "Yes, I will do (nicely)." is perfectly grammatical.  It also has nothing to do with the question:

> Will you be having cake?

At least, not without some very convoluted backstory where you ARE the cake you're eating.  I've read weirder stories, but that way lies madness.

What I'm pointing out here is that the question imposes a subset of possible meanings.  There are ways to parse these words that result in them being grammatical but in the context of the question those grammatical meanings are nonsensical.  So the answer is wrong.  Just for a different reason.

Which means it's not the best answer to use in this question. You want something objectively ungrammatical. This is about English, not logic or philosophy.

So I vote for a new answer:

`Yes, I will a.`

If you know how to parse that into any meaning at all, you're more clever than I.

Comment: As another side note: nice to see you again Mari-Lou!

Comment: I've edited my question, I don't think it invalidates your answer, but you can "fix" it up, if you want.

Comment: No problem.  Just glad if it helped.

Comment: Your final option is clearly a perfectly logical (and grammatical?) prerequisite to the one in the question. After all, as Scandos say when they want to say “in for a penny, in for a pound”: once you will A, you will B(e) too! ;-)

Comment: On a more serious note, and with all due respect to Master Yoda, his usage is significantly different from the case in question here. The _be_ is required in his statement because you have to repeat the main auxiliary/prop verb in an echo statement if it's in a different form than in the statement it echoes, and Yoda’s is: “I **am** not afraid” — “You will **be**”. But here we have “Will you **be** X” — “Yes, I will **be** ” with the same form. That's why you can leave it out here, but not in Yoda’s example. And I cannot think of any situation where “Yes, I will be” (with the ‘yes’) ->

Comment: -> changes the underlying construction in a way that causes the form of the verb to be different, because if an echo statement causes such a change, _it’s generally considered to be disagreement rather than agreement_. “Are you rich?” — “*Yes, I will be” doesn't work; but “Are you rich?” — “No, but I will be” is fine. So with the **agreement** of ‘yes’, I can't think of any situation where the main echo/prop verb would be included naturally.

Comment: @Mari-LouA And a merry new year to you.  Wish I knew how to strike up a chat with you.

Comment: I wouldn't want you catching my flu... *cough*  yes, I really am sick: see my last question. *cough* *cough* and  *achoo* Anyway, thanks for posting a good answer.

Comment: How... cryptic...

Comment: Many sentences are grammatical even if they are unidiomatic. I think it's better to shorten your answer. @JanusBahsJacquet Why don't you post it as an answer? I think your comment answers the question.

Answer (score -3):

Grammatically, questions are answered depending on the auxiliary verb used in the question.

For example:

> A: Do you read Shakespeare?
>
> B: Yes, I do

or

> A:Will you go to the party?
>
> B: Yes, I will

or

> A:Can you write with your left-hand?
>
> B: Yes, I can. Look...

If we analyze the answers, it is clear that the answers are formed based on the auxiliary verbs and verbs of the sentence are not taken.

Another example:

> A: Did you have to go to the theatre again that day?
>
> B: Yes, I did. I could not come back home without the umbrella

Based on this, in sentences where "be" is not auxiliary, it is not grammatically correct to answer "Yes, I will be". To be clear, the following example can be considered:

A:Will you be able to open the file if you get the password?
B: Yes, I will.

However, in sentences where "will be" is a grammar verb, as in Future Continuous Tense it is correct to answer as "Yes, I will be". This is again based on what has been explained above.

Comment: You were going great up until the second to last sentence where I agree with absolutely everything you say except for the word 'not'

Comment: Consider that "Yes, I will be" is an abbreviated version of "Yes, I will be doing whatever it is you just said."  This is perfectly legitimate usage, even in relatively formal circumstances.

Comment: This line of reasoning might work better to analyse “Yes, I will be” if you added an example that had “will be” in the question, e.g. Q: “Will you be coming to the party?” A: …

Comment: Unfortunately, you are right. I really forgot the case of "will be" in Future Continuous Tense use :). But what I thought of when answering the question is the case of ''will be " in sentences like : A: Will you be able to open it if you get the password? B: Yes, I will.                                        This is the case where "be'' what I call "a sentence verb" and not auxiliary. I noticed that some learners make mistake in such cases and write the short answer with "be".

Comment: *when answering the question,